# About CS50 Pset6 DNA, it overcounts STR for large.cvs

Tags: python, string, cs50

I'm working on pset6, DNA problem. This code is working for small.cvs but when I try the large one it overestimates the STR count. I guess the problem is when it tries to compare strings. But still don't know how to fix it. I checked that the counting is correct for the "TTTTTTCT" sequence but for the remaining STRs, the counting is in all cases larger than it should.

```
import sys
import csv

def main():
    while (len(sys.argv) != 3):
        print ("ERROR. Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
        break

    list_str = {}

#load the STRs to analyse
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
        readcsv = csv.reader (csvfile)
        ncol = len(next(readcsv))
        csvfile.seek(0)
        header = list()

        for line in readcsv:
            a = sum(1 for line in readcsv)
        for i in range(ncol):
            list_str[line[i]] = 0
            header.insert (i, line [i])
            print (f"{header[i]}")

#open an work with the sequence file
    sequence = open(sys.argv[2], 'r')
    seq_r = sequence.read()

    for k in list_str.keys():
        #print (f"keu {k}")
        p = 0
        seq = len(seq_r)

        while p < seq:
            if seq_r[p:(p + len(k))] == k: 
                list_str[k] += 1
                p += len(k) 
            else: p += 1
                #print (f" sequenci encontrada{list_str[k]} y {k}")

        print (f"nro de {k} {list_str[k]}")

    with open(sys.argv[1]) as csvfile:
        readcsv = csv.reader (csvfile)
        next(csvfile)

        find = False

        for row in readcsv:
            for j in range(1,ncol):
                #print(f"header :{header[j]}")
                if int(row [j]) == int(list_str[header[j]]): 
                    print (f"row {row[j]} list {list_str[header[j]]}")
                    find = True
                else: 
                    find = False
                    break

            if find == True: print (f"{row [0]}")
main()
```

Comment: Don't you have an indentation issue on the second for loop in the first csv read ? As is, the second loop in only going to work on the last line

Comment: Hi Javier, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing happened to me, and then I saw the specifications of the pset.

We need to find the "**longest run of consecutive repeats of the STR**". Not the total count of STRs. It works for the small.csv as in my case too, so try to search for the longest consecutive occurrences of the specific STR.